# How to round micros?

Tags: floating-point, precision, currency, floating-accuracy

In JavaScript, Python, and possibly other languages, if you round the value `37.305` to 2 decimal places, you get the wrong value:

```
Number(37.305).toFixed(2) => 37.30 // Should be 37.31
```

One solution to the precision problems when representing money is to use [micros](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/reference/v201808/LineItemService.Money). That is, $1.00 => 1,000,000 micros.

My question is: how could I round the value representing $37.305 in micros (`37305000`) to 2 decimal places (where the result should be `37.31`?

Comment: Why do you think that rounding 37.305 to 37.30 is wrong? That's the correct thing to do if you're using round-to-even or bankers rounding. There's more ways to round .x5 than the elementary school rule of "always round halves up".

Comment: Then the rounding should be consistent. `Number(37.305001).toFixed(2) => 37.31`. If you have $1,000 / 7 => 142.857143, which you'll want to round to $142.86. At least that's how my bank would charge me if that's what I owed them =)

Comment: There are libraries to handle exact decimal calculations (not based on float); which language are you targeting?

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira: you might want to read [the Wikipedia page on rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding).

Comment: @Benjamin The exact case of 37.305 rounded to 2 being 37.30 can be seen in JavaScript, Python 2, Python 3. PHP 7 rounds it to 37.31.

Comment: You should really not use floating point values if you really care about precision and rounding; use a decimal library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To round a representation (in micros) *R* to *n* decimal places (in the represented value):

- Let *m* be 10<sup>6−*n*</sup>. This gives us the position value where we round for *n* decimal places.
- Let *r* be the residue of *R* modulo *m*. For example, when rounding 37305000 micros to two decimal places, *m* is 10000, and *r* is 5000.
- Let *s* be 0 or *m* according to the desired rounding rule (which is not stated in the question). For example, for round-to-nearest, if *r* < *m*/2, let *s* be 0 (round down). If *r* > *m*/2, let *s* be *m* (round up). If *r* = *m*/2, use the desired rule for breaking ties. This might be to round up, to round down, or to round depending on the next higher digit of *m*. For example, if the rule is to round ties to even, examine the last digit of *R*/*m* truncated to an integer. If it is even, set *s* to 0. If it is odd, set *s* to *m*.
- The desired rounded result is *R*−*r*+*s*.

The above suffices for non-negative *R*. To support negative numbers, adjustments may be needed for selecting the residue and applying the rounding rule to select *s*. These are fairly simple but depend on what residue or remainder operations are convenient in the programming language being used and on what rounding rule is desired.